# Eigenvalues when mapping from one basis to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say I have a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$. I know eigenvalues do not change when I change my basis for $V$ on both the vectors from the domain as well as the ones in the $\Im(T)$ to the same basis. That is $$\det(\mu_{AA}-\lambda I)=\det(\mu_{BB}-\lambda I)$$ where $A,B$ are different basis for $V$ and $\mu_{XX}$ is the transformation matrix for T with respect to the basis $X$ in both its domain and its image.

Are the previous eigenvalues the same if I consider the matrix for the same linear transformation $T$ but with basis $A$ for the domain and basis $B$ for the image? (That is $\mu_{AB}$)
Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe the answer is no. In general, the roots of

$$\det(\mu_{AB}-\lambda I)=0$$

are not the eigenvalues of $T$.

For instance, take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $T$ the identity, $A$ the canonical basis, $B$ an arbitrary basis, and $S$ the change of basis matrix that takes a vector from its canonical representation to its $B$ representation. Then $\mu_{AB}=SI=S$ so what is written above becomes, in this case, the condition for the eigenvalues of the matrix $S$ and thus a positive answer to your question would imply that $S$ has both eigenvalues equal to $1$, which is not true in general.

I hope this helps and I'm sorry for my previous answer which was wrong (now deleted).

Comment: Yeah, I was playing around with some homework and noticed a counterexample too, which lead to my question. I do wonder what the relationship is between those eigenvalues of a transformation; the ones you get when going from say, base $A$ to $B$ and base $A$ to base $C$. It would seem they have to be somehow related if they represent the same transformation in a sense

Comment: I don't see how they can be related, as you're basically just using the wrong equation. What is inside the determinant in your equation is supposed to just be a matrix representation of the linear transformation $T-\lambda I$. You're free to do so in a basis $A$ for domain and $B$ for codomain and write $\det(\mu_{AB}-\lambda I_{AB})=0$, but then the identity transformation will $\textbf{not}$ be represented by the identity matrix, i.e., $I_{AB}$ is not the identity matrix. If you write it as such, the equation no longer represents what you want.

Comment: In the example I gave, I showed that this mistake leads you to the eigenvalues of a non-singular matrix S... $\textit{any}$ non-singular matrix S, which, apart from $0$, can have any random set of eigenvalues. So maybe, at best, you would get something that is related to both T and the change of basis from the different basis that you're using. But in general, I believe that what you get is the eigenvalues for the product $Sμ_{AA}$. I mean, this is a relation that... well, it's interesting to think about, but I don't see it being a very useful one.

Comment: Ahhh, that's the key I was missing. The Identity matrix would change to the change of basis matrix, right?

Comment: Exactly. That's precisely what I had also missed in my previous answer